# How to remotely connect to a router which is behind an ISP provided modem?

Tags: networking, router, ip, modem

I have ISP/Broadband Modem which provides internet. On its LAN port - I connected another Asus RT-AX88U router. Now on that Asus router, I enabled remote managing in order to connect to that router remotely when needed.

The problem is that the router behind the modem does not have a public IP but on an internal 192.168.x.x. IP address. So I do not have a direct public IP address for the router; only to the modem.

How to connect to the router remotely? Maybe somehow need to do port forwarding or some other setup?

Comment: Have you tried to forward port (80 or 443) to the device then viewing the configuration page in a browser?

Comment: What models are the modem and router? Can the modem be set to bridge mode and no DHCP?

Comment: Router is Asus rt-ax88u

Comment: What is the exact make an model of the modem? The truth is that if the modem can be set to bridge-mode, you could just connect to the public IP address of the modem and that would give you the router config page. Or the modem itself needs to have some kind of setting in place.